# Encrypt in PHP, Decrypt in Python (des)

Tags: php, python, encryption

I have PHP code:

```
$source = 'test message';
$crypt_key = '01234567';
$td = mcrypt_module_open('des', '', 'ecb', '');
$key = substr($crypt_key, 0, mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td));
$iv_size = mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td);
# MCRYPT_RAND = 2
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND); 

if (mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv) != -1) {
  $crypt = mcrypt_generic($td, $source);
  mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
  mcrypt_module_close($td);
}
$tokenHex = '';
$tokenLength = strlen($crypt);
for ($i = 0; $i < $tokenLength; $i++) {
  $tokenHex .= sprintf("%02x", ord($crypt{$i}));
}
echo($tokenHex);
```

Result:

```
8998c67c86cd5d4d0221e1bee3f3e03e
```

Please, help! How this can be decrypted in Python? Thanks!

I try like this:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import Blowfish
import binascii
key = b'01234567'
c1  = Blowfish.new(key, Blowfish.MODE_ECB)
res = c1.decrypt(binascii.unhexlify('8998c67c86cd5d4d0221e1bee3f3e03e'))
print(res)
```

But result:

```
b'\xbbU;\x8d\x97{\xbc\x01I\x8bV\x10f%\xabh'
```

I also try:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES
des = DES.new('01234567', DES.MODE_ECB)
s1 = binascii.unhexlify('8998c67c86cd5d4d0221e1bee3f3e03e')
print( des.encrypt(s1))
```

But result wrong again:

```
b't\xceS\x0b\x97\x14S}\x14\xcc\xf8\x91e\x83e\xd9
```

Comment: use pycrypt .... that is probably ideal

Comment: i try, but it doesn't help me restore my initial message

Comment: If you want to decrypt with DES, why do you use Blowfish? DES != Blowfish

Comment: I also did it next way but result wrong again..
I have no idea how I can solve this problem...

Comment: of coarse its wrong ,... you are encrypting something thats already encrypted ...

Comment: I'm so sorry for my inadvertence. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

use decrypt instead of encrypt (in your second pycrypto example)  (assuming you want to decrypt ... and not encrypt

```
>>> print( des.decrypt(s1))
test message
```